# C: Select a substring, n columns wide from a multibyte string

Tags: c, string, multibyte

I have a `char *` string in C which is based on user input. From this string, I'd like to pick a substring starting from the 1st position such that the resulting substring is n columns wide on a fixed-width terminal.

Having never worked with non-ASCII characters in the past, I'm at a complete loss as to how to work on this problem, or even start. Some preliminary searches suggested using `libiconv` but that doesn't seem to help. I also tried using `wchar.h`, wide character support, but I'm not sure of that's the right way to go.

EDIT: This is what I tried in the first attempt:

```
static int
count_n_cols (const char *mbs, char *mbf, const int n)
{
  wchar_t wc;
  int     bytes;
  int     remaining = strlen(mbs);
  int     cols = 0;
  int     wccols;

  while (*mbs != '\0' && cols <= n)
    {
      bytes = mbtowc (&wc, mbs, remaining);
      assert (bytes != 0);  /* Only happens when *mbs == '\0' */
      if (bytes == -1)
        {
          /* Invalid sequence. We'll just have to fudge it. */
          return cols + remaining;
        }
      mbs += bytes;
      remaining -= bytes;
      wccols = wcwidth(wc);
      *mbf += wc;
      cols += (wccols == -1? 1 : wccols);
    }
  return cols;
}
```

Comment: Added a function I tried to write. I'm not sure if this is the best way going forward.

Comment: What problems do you have with your code? At first sight it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to count the number of utf-8 sequences to perform your substring without doing any conversion. You can calculate the number of bytes in corresponds to each 'column' by reading the first byte of the sequence, as specified by the utf-8 standard. Here is some sample code, based off of your example function and [Wikipedia's UTF-8 description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

```
static int count_n_cols (const char *mbs, char *mbf, const int n)
{
    int bytes;
    int length = strlen(mbs);
    int cols = 0;

    for (bytes = 0; bytes < length; bytes++)
    {
        if (mbs[bytes] == '\0' || cols >= n)
            break;
        else if ((mbs[bytes] & 0x80) == 0)  // the first bit is 0
        {
            cols++;
        }
        else if ((mbs[bytes] & 0xE0) == 0xC0)   //the first 3 bits are 110
        {
            //two bytes in utf8 sequence
            cols++;
            bytes++;
        }
        else if ((mbs[bytes] & 0xF0) == 0xE0)   //the first 4 bits are 1110
        {
            //three bytes in utf8 sequence
            cols++;
            bytes += 2;
        else if ((mbs[bytes] & 0xF8) == 0xF0)   //the first 5 bits are 11110
        {
            //four bytes in utf8 sequence
            cols++;
            bytes += 3;
        }
        else
        {
            putc(mbs[bytes],stdout);
            printf(" non_ascii %d\n", mbs[bytes] & 0x80);
        }
    }
    strncpy(mbf, mbs, bytes);
    mbf[bytes] = '\0';
    return cols;
}
```